# Command line Java run from the terminal on Mac pops up Java window in the Mac dashboard which disappears after the jobs is done

Tags: java, macos

The problem is that when the command is executed I get a Java Window pop up briefly in the dashboard on a mac.  Is there anyway to prevent this from happening.  The command line Java does not have any gui to it.  So it should not be bringing up any gui or windows.  The window that pops up is only in the dashboard with a picture of a coffee cup indicating there is a Java process running.  And when the job ends it goes away.  How can I make it so that user is not seeing this pop up?

Comment: This needs a lot more explanation. "When the command is executed"? What command? Executed how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. On a Mac it looks like I have to add this to the command line:

-Dapple.awt.UIElement=true

Which allows it to be run headless and will not pop up the java window in the dashboard.